# Sprite Kit game laggy in simulator with Xcode 7 / Swift 2

Tags: sprite-kit, ios-simulator, swift2, xcode7

After upgrading to Xcode 7 with Swift 2, my Sprite Kit project is very laggy on the simulator.

It previously would get 60 fps, and now it maxes out at 15 fps. (If I remove all textures, it goes up to 60, but even adding a single screen-sized texture drops it all the way down to 15 again.)

I've tried running in release mode as well as debug, and it makes no difference.

It's still smooth on the device.

Has anybody else had this issue? Any fixes? It just makes it hard to test.

Answer (score 0):

The simulator will almost always have lag due to the fact that your computer is emulating the device (so yes I have had your issue).  It is not really a problem with your App (unless you changed something massive in your App during the upgrade).  I cannot speak to why the frame rate dropped on the sim from the upgrade (probably something not optimized yet, plus more features in iOS 9 slowing down the sim), but as long as it is good on the device, you should be good.

If you elaborate on what your setup is (what device(s) you have, and computer hardware), and what you are releasing to, I can provide more accurate information.

Another thing that may help is restarting the computer, that always seems to help when Xcode gets funny.

Comment: Actually I may have gotten somewhere - I'm getting this warning, and it seems relevant: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks. Any thoughts?

Comment: Creating a new build scheme removes the warning, but the framerate hasn't changed.